# clang-tidy install

Tags: ubuntu, centos, fedora, clang

I have clang installed from packages on both Ubuntu 14.07, Centos 7 and Fedoara 22. I would like to use `clang-tidy` but can neither find a package nor how to install it without installing clang from source. That's something I would rather not do.

What am I missing?

I *might* be dense, if so please mock me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use your package manager to find out which package `clang-tidy` provides. For example on Fedora/CentOS:

```
dnf whatprovides '*/clang*tidy*'
```

On Debian/Ubuntu you can use an analogous `apt-file search` command.

However, on Fedora  23 `clang-tidy` just isn't packaged. No match is found.

There is even an open bug report: [Missing clang-query and clang-tidy](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1328091)

For Ubuntu/Debian, the LLVM project [maintains an llvm apt repostiory](http://apt.llvm.org/). This should be the easiest way to get the latest `clang-tidy`. After configuring that repository and doing an `apt-file update` and `apt-file search` should return the package that provides `clang-tidy`.

An alternative to building from source is to use the [upstream llvm pre-built binaries](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html) - they are available for Fedora, CentOS etc. For example the one for Fedora 23 does contain clang-tidy:

```
clang+llvm-3.8.0-x86_64-fedora23/bin/clang-tidy
```

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 29 includes `clang-tidy` in the main Fedora repository.  You can install it via:

```
dnf install clang-tools-extra
```